# Big Theta of Factorial Multiplied by a Coefficient

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

For a function with a run time of (cn)! where c is a coefficient >= 0 and c != n, would the tight bound of the run be Θ(n!) or Θ((cn)!)? Right now, I believe it would be Θ((cn)!) since they would differ by a coefficent >= n since cn != n.

Thanks!

Edit: A more specific example to clarify what I'm asking:

Will (7n)!, (5n/16)! and n! all be Θ(n!)?

Comment: An algorithm with a dataset size of "n" has an *IDENTICAL* "big-O" to a dataset of size "c * n".  There is no difference :)

Comment: I think you should provide a more detailed description of the algorithm to get a reasonable answer. I believe that for certain kinds of algorithms (super slow or super fast) you can't find big-Theta using conventional math functions (because `Θ` must lineary bound from above and below at the same time) . Sometimes you have to use some unconventional notations like `n^Θ(1)` which is "all polynomial algorithms" or some other way. See the definition of [exponential time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Exponential_time) for an example of such troubles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will (7n)!, (5n/16)! and n! all be Θ(n!)?

I think there are two answers to your question.

The shorter one is from the purely theoretical point of view. Of those 3 only the `n!` lies in the class of `Θ(n!)`. The second lies in the `O(n!)` (note big-O instead of big-Theta) and `(7n)!` is slower than `Θ(n!)`, it lies in `Θ((7n)!)`

There is also a longer but more practical answer. And to get to it we first need to understand what is the big deal with this whole big-O and big-Theta business in the first place?

The thing is that for many practical tasks there are many algorithms and not all of them are equally or even similarly efficient. So the practical question is: can we somehow capture this difference in performance in an easy to understand and compare way? And this  is the problem that big-O/big-Theta are trying to solve. The idea behind this method is that if we look at some algorithm with some complicated real formula for the exact time, there is only 1 term that grows faster than all others and thus dominates the time as the problem gets bigger. So let's compress this big formula to that dominant term. Then we can compare those terms and if they are different, we can easily say which is the better algorithm (`7*n^2` is clearly better than `2*n^3`).

Another idea is that the term "operation" is usually not that well defined at the level people usually think about algorithms. Which "operation" actually maps to a single CPU instruction and which to a few depends on many factors such as particular hardware. Also the instructions themselves can take different time to execute. Moreover sometimes the algorithm's working time is dominated by memory access than CPU instructions and those components are not easily additive. The morale of this story is that if two algorithms are different only in a scalar coefficient, you can't really compare those algorithms just theoretically. You need to compare some implementations in some particular environment. This is why algorithms complexity measure typically boils down to something like `O(n^k)` where `k` is a constant.

There is one more consideration: practicality. If the algorithm is some polynomial, there is a huge ***practical*** difference between cases `a=3` and `a=4` in `O(n^a)`. But if it is something like `O(2^(n^a))`, then there is not much difference what exactly the `a` as along as `a>1`. This is because `2^n` grows fast enough to make it impractical for almost any realistic `n` irrespective of `a`. So in practical terms it is often good enough approximation to put all such algorithms into a single "exponential algorithms" bucket and say they are all impractical even despite the fact there is a huge difference between them. This is where some mathematically unconventional notations like `2^O(n)` come from.

From this last practical perspective the difference between `Θ(n!)` and `Θ((7n)!)` is also very little: both are totally impractical because both lie beyond even the exponential bucket of `2^O(n)` (see [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) that shows that `n!` grows a bit faster than `(n/e)^n`). So it makes sense to put all such algorithms in another bucket of "factorial complexity" and mark them as impractical as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) to get that if c>1 then (cn)! is asymptotically larger than pow(c,n)*n!, which is not O(n!) since the quotient diverges. As a more elementary approach  consider this example for c=2: (2n)!=(2n)(2n-1)...(n+1)n!>n!n! and  (n!n!)/n!=n! diverges, so (2n)! is NOT O(n!).